# UIView CATransform3DMakeRotation horizontally from left to right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to rotate my view horizontally from left to right. So I am using `CATransform3DMakeRotation` to do rotation.

Here is my code,

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

[UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

newView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/2,0,1.0,0.0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This code really works, But it rotates my view half only.. I want to make full rotation.
So i changed the value `M_PI/2` into `M_PI`, like this

```
CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0,1.0,0.0);
```

But for this value, my view is not rotating at all. Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: Everything is fine it should work with: `CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0.0,1.0,0.0);`. I have tested Your code and it's working fine.

Comment: But for me its not working.. Are u sure, is t working for u.. Can u tel me whether the view is rotating from right to left or left to right?

Comment: can u pls upload ur sample.. So that i can check..

Comment: It's rotating from left to right. Ok, I will upload for You sample.

Comment: http://www10.zippyshare.com/v/53768291/file.html, hope it helps.

Comment: Ya it works, Thank You.. Here it takes mid point of view as origin.. Can u tel me how to fix origin for this rotation.. That means i want to rotate my view from start point, not from middle..

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease]; // Don't forget to release this! I added autorelease.
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewOutlet.frame.size.width, viewOutlet.frame.size.height);

[viewOutlet addSubview:imageView];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0];


[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
viewOutlet.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.5f);
viewOutlet.layer.transform =CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0,1.0,0.0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

** **viewOutlet** is Your view outlet so don't forget to IBOutlet it.

Comment: No, i dint want that.. But i got it.. Here is the code..  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
   
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
   
  [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
  [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
  
  newView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.5f);
  newView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0,1.0,0.0);
  [UIView commitAnimations];        Really thanks for your help :)

Comment: Again i got an issue with the same thing.. Whn i use this code for plain background or a simple it work awesome.. But when i am trying it with some othe view which as an imageview as background, the rotation from right to left is not happening.. Pls get me out of this.. Here is my code..

Comment: newView = [[UIView alloc] init];newView.frame = CGRectMake(189, 0, 389, self.view.frame.size.height);imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newView.frame.size.width, newView.frame.size.height);[newView addSubview:imageView];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0];

Comment: [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];  newView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.5f);  newView.layer.transform =CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0,1.0,0.0);
[UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: @user1402675: why You are doing everything programatically? Create `UIView` in Interface builder (or use which You have already like in my example "viewOutlet"). Replace Your created view with outlet and it will work. (Add imageView to this view as subview). Your code should look like in my updated answer look at it.

Comment: Ya i accept what u said. But actually i want to create animation like flip board. I have gone through several samples but i couldn't get anything from that.. I am simply trying rotate the view from left to right at swipe.. Any help or source ll be appreciated..